# Is it possible to display apps in frames? (Android)

Tags: android

What i want to do is to let my app provide the rendering-canvas for other apps, like a HTML iframes. So that i can run another app inside my app and display its "screen" on part of the physical screen.

Is it a possibility that this is how widgets are shown?

My guess is that it's probably not possible, but maybe someone here knows a way?

Comment: You may want to look into http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html Fragments.  Though I am unsure if they fit your needs.

Comment: Not exactly what i meant. What i'm trying to do is to start another app inside mine. Like display the facebook app or gmail app on half the screen and display youtube or whatever on the other half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it generically, but you can do it exactly the way it works with widgets. See [AppWidgetHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetHost.html).